# Spring MVC: Does this code make child-parent relationship between two context?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have learned how to configure spring MVC without web.xml and .xml files for parent and child context from this [link](http://kielczewski.eu/2013/11/spring-mvc-without-web-xml-using-webapplicationinitializer/). I saw how to programmatically make context hierarchy in [the official spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/) as follow.

```
ApplicationContext parent = new GenericXmlApplicationContext(ParentAnnotationConfig.class);
GenericApplicationContext child = new GenericApplicationContext(parent);
```

But the post from [the link](http://kielczewski.eu/2013/11/spring-mvc-without-web-xml-using-webapplicationinitializer/) don't have similar statements like above ones. Does this code make context hierarchy between two context or not?

Comment: It would have been nicer to give part of the code from the link. Link only anwers are normally deleted, but your question cannot be understood without going to the link. What will happen if the link becomes broken ?

Answer (score 0):

The code from the link you submitted uses Spring MVC. The programmatic method you show is independant of Spring MVC. It makes a big difference.

Spring MVC automagically creates parent child relations between the root context and the dispatcher servlet context(es). The wepapp should have :

- one single root context referenced in the `ServletContext`. It is supposed to be used for everything not directly related to the servlet : model, persistance and filters that can exist independantly of the servlet
- one context per dispatcher servlet constructed with the root context as parent. It is supposed to be used for controllers, views, interceptors

The parent-child relation ensure that you can access all beans from the controllers, but you cannot access web (servlet) beans from root contex.

To directly answer your question, I would say that the linked code does not explicitely build the context hierachy. The hierarchy is built by Spring MVC framework. So it does exist, and you must not try to generate it explicetely.